# Asp button to open new page without submit

Tags: asp.net

I have this aspx script for the button for pop-up:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewEntry" Text="Post Code Search" OnClick="btnNewEntry_Click" runat="Server" target="_blank"/>
```

and behind:

```
protected void btnNewEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "", "window.open('../search/postcode_search/Default.aspx?code="+ p +"','Post Code Search','width=800,height=300,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes'); popup_handle.focus();", true);

}
```

But as the button is clicked the pop-up is opened but the parent page is refreshed. Why it's so? any work around?

Comment: change the html to <input type="button" .... />

Comment: I cant. I need to use asp function.

Answer (score 1):

Page got refreshed when a request to server is made, and server controls like Button has a property AutoPostback = true by default which means whenever they are clicked a trip to server will be made. Set AutoPostback = false for insert button, and this will do the trick for you.

```
 or     

Add OnClientClick="return false;" ,

<asp:button ID="btninsert" runat="server" text="Button" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Comment: isn't the on client click what he needs to fire that window.open? If you just return false it would never execute anything or report a click. Turning autopostback off is the right approach as that will keep it from making the roundtrip to the server. However, I would suggest a control that is not server side and that just opens up a new page that happens to be the aspx page you need. You can pass it the necessary information from what you have client side.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little explanation of what is actually happening with your code will help. We have already discussed the auto postback, so you know that clicking that button will send the event back to the server. The page initializes again and reloads the view state and all of the posted data. After that, the button click event is handled.

At this point, your code writes the window.open script to the page. Keep in mind this is no where specific. This is just script that is added some where on the page and executed. The view state then gets updated and the page is sent back to the client. If the user reloads the page, that script is going to execute again.

Your best bet is going to be converting that to a client side button only. Find a way to get the necessary data back from the server before loading your popup. The easiest way to do that is make an AJAX call and open your pop up on success from your end point.

Comment: The thing why I did this on server side, is that I need to send the data to that popup window. Im sending parent`s url parameters where. Is there a way to do so using AJAX?

Comment: The data of "code=p", or is there additional processing that you need to do on the server side before loading the page? It is pretty easy to call an end point via ajax and return whatever id you need and then process that return data however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.**Updated** one.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewEntry" Text="Post Code Search" OnClick="btnNewEntry_Click" runat="Server" target="_blank"
OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('../search/postcode_search/Default.aspx?code=+ p','Post Code Search','width=800,height=300,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes').focus();return false;"/>
```

Issue was due to "+ p +".

Comment: Hi ADamal, im getting error: The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

So as advised, i decided to go to client side. Here is my script:

```
<button  onclick="OpenPopup()" type="button">Post Code Search</button>
```

and javascript code above it:

```
    <script>

 function OpenPopup() {
    var getQueryString = function ( field, url ) {
    var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
};
var str = getQueryString('code');
    if (str != null) {
    p = str.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
        }
    else { 
    p = "";
    }
    var url = "../search/postcode_search/Default.aspx?code=" + p;
    window.open(url, "Post Code Search", "toolbar=no, location=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, width=750,height=400,left=430,top=100");
    return false;
    }


</script>
```

so basically what it does, it grabs parameter from parent window url and adds to popup window url. My parent window url:

/Customer.aspx?code=V6E%20111&firstname=MyName

I hope it helps for others as well. Thanks for help guys.